# Highlight issues with twitter bootstrap buttons

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap

I having an issue using bootstrap and buttons...

Example: I have an ng-view with a button, where you get to another page. If we go back with the back button of the browser or another button on the side, you will see the button is still highlighted as active. Firefox etc. are working fine. The default browser of android is not working correctly as discribed. :-(

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VrGnL/9/

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="go('/list')">Click</button>
```

How can I solve this? I searched a lot, but could not find anybody with this issue. Am I missing something?

ICE

PS: Kind of the same problem, scrolling on a touch device will highlight the button, where you start to scroll, which is also not the indented behaviour, I guess

Comment: You need to add a fiddle with code that shows what is not working. Here is a link to a empty fiddle that already has bootstrap included for you: http://jsfiddle.net/5JybP/10/

Comment: Can at least somebody confirm that there is an issue on mobile devices? Maybe I am doing something strange, that is causing the problem.

Comment: You could just write a snippet of javascript that runs on page load `$(document).ready(function(){ //do something })` to change it back if you need it to, a bit of a hack but it would work.

Comment: Can you give me a hint, how to do this? If possible without jquery... I tried document.activeElement.blur();, which has no effect

Answer (score 0):

Found an work around...
The android browser has same issues with the hover event, because it seems that
it 'emulates a mouse pointer' on a touch and leave the mouse pointer there. So if you go
back, the mouse pointer is still there and the hover event is triggered.

So delete the hover events from bootstrap works. As there is no sense in hover events on
mobile devices, it is not a real issue...

Thanks @Joshua Robinson for your help!